# PHP mcrypt_generic() method get a different result from C# and Python

Tags: c#, php, python, encryption

I have written a Python version of **DES3** encryption method to encrypt the data send to the server, but the server side said that it could not decrypt the requested data.

So I have to check the source code. And found that the encryption result of PHP version are different from Python and C#.

The algorithm used is DES3, Mode: ECB, in such mode, IV is unnecessary. And the padding used in Python and C# is Zeros (that is the padding string consists of bytes set to zero). ***I do not know how PHP dealing with padding.***

The key used is **1234567887654321**, the plain is **hello**, IV is eight empty space (non-used).

The hex dump of PHP encryption result is

```
77 2c fe 6e c1 df 71 94
```

The hex dump of Python and C# are

```
BC 17 0C 67 7D 06 5C AA
```

Anybody could tell me what's wrong with the PHP code?

The following are the source code

> PHP

```
function encrypt($plain, $key, $iv) {
    /* Open module, and create IV */
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');

    /* Initialize encryption handle */
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv) != -1) {

        /* Encrypt data */
        $c_t = mcrypt_generic($td, $plain);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

        /* Clean up */
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
    }
    return $c_t;
}
```

> Python

```
def encrypt(text, key, iv=''):
    cypher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_ECB, iv)

    padding_length = (8 - len(text) % 8) % 8
    padding = '\x00' * padding_length
    return cypher.encrypt(text + padding)
```

> C#

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plain, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Create a MemoryStream to accept the encrypted bytes 
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    TripleDES alg = TripleDES.Create(); 

    alg.Key = Key;
    alg.IV = IV;
    alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    alg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
       alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Write the data and make it do the encryption 
    cs.Write(plain, 0, plain.Length);
    cs.Close();

    byte[] cypher = ms.ToArray();
    return cypher;
}
```

Comment: Always supply correct arguments. 3DES should have a 24-byte key. Do not rely on default key extension, it can very between implementations. Do not use a string as the key, extend it with a function such as PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function). Do not use ECB mode. DES and 3DES should not be used for new work, use AES which replaced DES as the encryption standard.

Comment: @zaph, you could not control which encryption algorithm to use if you were only the client. And also using AES or DES is somewhat depends on the concrete situation, AES would not be the best one at all cases.

Comment: This is where security disasters occur. Using poor security because it is the easy solution, were is always an excuse. Using a short string for the key without key extension is not justifiable. Security "bugs" and poor design mean the loss of security, not just a re-boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of *Triple* DES, you will should be passing in a 24 byte key. Since you are passing in 16 bytes different implementations use different methods to expand this key to 24 bytes.

It appears that in Python/C# the 16 byte key is extended by cycling/repeating it around to make this 24 bytes. So for example:

```
1234567887654321
```

becomes

```
123456788765432112345678
```

PHP on the other hand appears to simply pad the key with nulls (`\x00`) which you can verify by doing

```
$output1 = bin2hex(encrypt($str, "1234567887654321", ""));
$output2 = bin2hex(encrypt($str, "1234567887654321\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", ""));

echo $output1 == $output2;  // true!
```

If you mimic this Python/C# "cycling" behaviour manually with PHP, you will get a consistent output for all 3 languages:

```
$output = bin2hex(encrypt($str, "123456788765432112345678", ""));
echo $output; // bc170c677d065caa
```

Although you can simply extend the 16-byte key to 24-bytes by simple cycling/repeating it, just go for a fully random 24-byte key instead for max security. You can read [more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) (you want keying option #1)

Comment: @Martine, you are right. I have found a similar description on PHP manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#47973